# Is there a more concise way to write this?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a project that displays a map by searching line by line. Here is a brief version of how it looks:

```
xpos=1
ypos=1
#xpos and ypos are the player's coordinates
running=True
while running:
    if xpos==1:
        if ypos==1:
            print('x . . ')
        if ypos==2:
            print('. x .')
        if ypos==3:
            print('. . x')
    else:
        print('. . .')
```

... and so on. The project I am creating needs a 50 by 50 map, so this method seems like a waste of computing power, along with time it would take to type. Is there a better way I can do this? Sorry in advance for the disgusting code!
EDIT: Is there a way I can use for or while loops to complete this?

Comment: Do you know about loops? Hint: Think about how would you use a `for` loop to iterate over the y positions and print an `x` in the place you want, and a `.` everywhere else?

Comment: I was thinking about for loops, but I couldn't find a way to get it to work as I wanted. If you could specify (give me more hints bc im bad at coding) that would be great!

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your attempt with loops, and then ask a _specific_ question about what went wrong with that attempt. "How do I improve this code" is too broad for Stack Overflow. It looks like you need to go through a tutorial or talk to a real tutor, and Stack Overflow is neither. There are many good resources on loops available online. For each line, you want to loop over all the possible `y` values in that line. If the `y` for the current loop is equal to `ypos`, print an `x`, else print a `.`.

Comment: Sorry, I've only used Stack Overflow a few times. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library **graphics.py** and show the movement of a bookmark on the map, for example, This code moves a circle on a straight line. This move can include the page line by line.

```
from graphics import GraphWin,  Circle, Point
import time

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Back and Forth', 300, 300)
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 299, 299)

    cir1 = Circle(Point(40,100),5)
    cir1.setFill("yellow")
    cir1.draw(win)
    for i in range(46):
        cir1.move(5, 0)
        time.sleep(.05)

    for i in range(46):
        cir1.move(-5, 0)
        time.sleep(.05)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

https://pypi.org/project/graphics.py/

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html

Comment: Thanks for the info! Does this work with Python 3, because the links you included only use Python 2?